# Grail/GORM Data Service @Query - Join with Multiple Conditions

Tags: jpa, grails, grails-orm

I have the following two grails domain classes

```
class FaceData {
    ... other fields omitted ...
    static hasMany = [landmarks: FaceLandmark]
}

class FaceLandmark {
    FaceData faceData
    String name
    float x
    float y
}
```

and the following GORM Data Service

```
import grails.gorm.services.Query
import grails.gorm.services.Service

@Service(FaceData)
abstract class FaceDataDataService {
    ... other methods omitted ...

    @Query("select $fd from ${FaceLandmark fl} inner join ${FaceData fd = fl.faceData} where $fl.name = $name")
    abstract Set<FaceData> findByHasFaceLandmarkWithName(String name)
}
```

I'm trying to define a finder that will get the opposite of `findByHasFaceLandmarkWithName`.  I want it to return only `FaceData` objects that do not have any `FaceLandmarks` with a specific name.  The SQL for what I'm looking for follows.  How do I specify that using an `@Query` annotation?

```
select fd.*
from face_landmark fl
right outer join face_data fd
    on fd.id = fl.face_data_id 
    and fl.name = 'some value'
where fl.name is null;
```

Comment: and why not try "DetachCriteria" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
    @Query("select $fd from ${FaceLandmark fl} right join ${FaceData fd} on $fd = $fl.faceData and $fl.name = $name where $fl is null")
    abstract List<FaceData> findByFaceLandmarkWithNameIsMissing(String name)
```